# Search for a special character in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have some special character in SQL Server 2005 on one of the field which has Japanese data.
Due to which Cube processing fails with Attribute Key not found error.

The value interpreted by Analysis Services server is '野田　', but the value in db is 野田.

[Note the space after value '野田　']

[image]

Am trying to search for all the rows that contain this special character at end of the data in last_name column.

For this, I tried below query, but it doesnt give me the incorrect results.

```
select * from [#temp1]
where convert(nvarchar,last_name)  like convert(nvarchar,'%　')
```

[image]

I want the rows that contains special character ('　') at end of values in last_name field.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you know the ASCII value for the special character? Maybe that's not a space, but something else. I would use `ASCII` & `SUBSTRING` to confirm what the character is and then use `CHAR` to search for that exact ASCII value.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know ASCII value. Not sure how I can get it. Yea, it doesnt seems to be a space.

Comment: That's why you use the `ASCII` and `SUBSTRING` functions to get the character. You already know what row it's in. Getting a bit long for comments, so I'll post this as an answer below.

Comment: Sure.. I totally forgot about ASCII..  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `REVERSE` and `SUBSTRING`

Like this,

```
select * from [#temp1]
where SUBSTRING(REVERSE(last_name),1,1)=' '
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a trailing character that isn't actually a space, but which shows up as one in SSMS (or whatever else you're using to view the data). You need to find what that character actually is, so I would try something like this:

```
SELECT
    last_name,
    ASCII(SUBSTRING(last_name, LEN(last_name), 1))
FROM
    #temp1
```

If you know the id value or some other way to see that row then add in a `WHERE` clause.

Once that's done, you should be able to find all instances of that data with:

```
SELECT
    *    -- Get whatever columns you need
FROM
    #temp1
WHERE
    last_name LIKE '%' + CHAR(<value found above>)
```